# What can explain a Lock/deadlock between 3 transactions that have no row in common?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Lock (and a deadlock) between 3 transactions that have no row in common an I don't understand why. This is what the user does :

- On client 1 we do a bulk insert of 383 orders;
- On Client 2 we try to update the order A and we are lock on the instruction DELETE TBL_MSG WHERE ID = 345454541216;
- On Client 3 we try to update the order B and we are lock on the instruction DELETE TBL_MSG WHERE ID = 345848487778;
- When Client 1 commit it's transaction then the lock on Client 2 and Client 3 is released and Client 2 crash with the error 00060 [Transaction Deadlock] with Client 3

What can explain this scenario if no row are in common between Client 1/Client 2/Client 3 ?

Comment: there should be a trace file with the deadlock details you can review

Comment: By bulk insert, do you mean direct path insert for 383 rows? That seems over kill and will probably mean you are wasting a lot of space. Why are you deleting for your update? My gut is telling me you have unindexed foreign keys in play.

Comment: @AndrewSayer yes I start a transaction and insert 343 rows (more than 383 rows in fact because I insert also rows in child table). we are deleting for update because we clean child tables before to fill it (the sample SQL was an SQL on one of the child table). can you explain about unindexed foreign key ?

Comment: What's bulk about the insert? I'm concerned you're trying to do direct path inserts here which would be a terrible idea. For an insert into a table to block a delete rows which have nothing in common, you are probably doing a direct path insert (which requires a exclusive lock on the table). For client 2 and client 3 to be interfering with each other, you probably have another table level lock which are required when deleting from tables which is a parent table to a table with to index on the foreign key column.

Comment: Your comments refer to child tables, but the question doesn't mention any parent/child relationship; please update your question to fully explain the situation, including what the trace file tells you. Do you have triggers on the tables? If so I'd maybe be looking for side-effects from those rather than just the actual statements you are issuing.